# convert xml data into pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I want to turn the following data into a dataframe, de xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file>
  <SORT_INFO>
    <sort_type>sort order</sort_type>
  </SORT_INFO>
  <ALL_INSTANCES>
    <instance>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <start>11.24</start>
      <end>31.24</end>
      <code>19. Luis Alehandru Paz Mulato</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>America de Cali</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.6</pos_x>
      <pos_y>34.2</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <start>11.24</start>
      <end>31.24</end>
      <code>19. Luis Alehandru Paz Mulato</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>America de Cali</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Positional attacks</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.6</pos_x>
      <pos_y>34.2</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <start>14.43</start>
      <end>34.43</end>
      <code>6. Felipe Jaramillo Velasquez</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>America de Cali</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Positional attacks</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>38.6</pos_x>
      <pos_y>26.2</pos_y>
    </instance>
  </ALL_INSTANCES>
```

After </ALL_INSTANCES> there is a little bit more, but I only need the data inside the 'instance' tags as if those were the rows. So my columns would be as follows:

```
['ID', 'start', 'end', 'code', 'group1', 'text1', 'group2', 'text2', 'group3', 'text3', 'pos_x','pos_y']
```

and the first row would be:

```
['1', '11.24', '31.24', '19. Luis Alehandru Paz Mulato', 'Team', 'America de Cali', 'Action', 'Passes accurate', 'Half', '1st half', '52.6','34.2']
```

It is my firts time working with xml files, thank you so much for your help.

I already tried the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 

xtree = et.parse("players_vs_nacional_0-3.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()
    

for node in xroot:         
    id_action = node.find("ID").text   
    start = node.find("start").text 
    end = node.find("end").text 
    code = node.find("code").text 
    posx = node.find("pos_x").text 
    posy = node.find("pos_y").text
```

But I got the error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I believe it is because the first nodes don't contain what I was looking for ("ID", "start", "end", etc), but I couldn't get passed that and I am also having trouble trying to figure out how to get the info out of the  tags because there are three of them for every  and I need them all and in the same row.

Comment: Just updated my question trying to be a little bit more specific, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for something like this:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
inst = """[your xml above, corrected; it's missing a closing </file> tag]"""
doc = etree.XML(inst.encode())

rows =[]
targets = doc.xpath('//instance')
columns = [elem.tag for elem in targets[0].xpath('.//*') if len(elem.getchildren())==0 ]

for target in targets:
    row = []
    for item in target.xpath('.//*'):            
        if len(item.getchildren())>0:
            continue
        else:
            row.append(item.text.strip())
    rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
df
```

Output:

```
ID  start   end     code    group   text    group   text    group   text    pos_x   pos_y
0   1   11.24   31.24   19. Luis Alehandru Paz Mulato   Team    America de Cali     Action  Passes accurate     Half    1st half    52.6    34.2
1   2   11.24   31.24   19. Luis Alehandru Paz Mulato   Team    America de Cali     Action  Positional attacks  Half    1st half    52.6    34.2
2   3   14.43   34.43   6. Felipe Jaramillo Velasquez   Team    America de Cali     Action  Positional attacks  Half    1st half    38.6    26.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a nested list/dictionary comprehension with `enumerate` to number the multiple `label` nodes. Then pass liat of dictionaries into `DataFrame` constructor. Below merges dictionaries using [latest method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/1422451) available  in Python 3.5+:

```py
data = [{ **{n.tag:n.text for n in inst},    
          **{l.tag+str(i+1):l.text for i,l in enumerate(inst.findall("label/*"))} }
           for inst in xroot.findall(".//instance") ]
           
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```